# CFCHART - How do I get the Y-Axis label to show on the right side only?

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I am using cfchart and I cannot figure out how to get the Y-Axis to only show on the right side.   I have opened up the web charts editor in the coldfusion/charts directory without any luck.

I found [this link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2008/11/11/Ask-a-Jedi-Two-yAxis-for-ColdFusion-Charts) that shows 2 axis but it did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the primaryYAxisPlacement property

```
<frame xDepth="12" yDepth="11" primaryYAxisPlacement="Right"/>
```